# Regular expression to get words that begin with a capital letter

Tags: java, regex

I have a text file that is like 2 pages long and I need to write a regular expression that will extract words that begin with a capital letter.
Some examples of words that I would like to get (but not limited to these) are:

```
British Indian Ocean Territory
People's Republic of China Confederation of Independent States
French Southern and Antarctic Lands
Gilbert and Ellia Islands
Iraq-Saudia Arabia Neutral Zone
Juan de Nova Island 
St. Vincent and the Grenadines 
Trust Territory of the Pacific 
Washington, D.C.
```

The regex that I came up with is:

```
"((?:[A-Z][a-z]+\\s){2,4}?) || ((?:[A-Z][a-z]+\\s){1,2}of(?:\\s[A-Z][a-z]+){1,2}) || ((?:[A-Z][a-z]+\\s){1,2}and(?:\\s[A-Z][a-z]+){1,2})"
```

Comment: So... is there something wrong with the regex? If so, what?

Comment: What you are trying to do is impossible with regexes, since you seem want to extract not only single words but expressions (eg: `Republic of China Confederation of Independent States`). Keep in mind that it is impossible without using a dictionary.

Comment: If I run my regex as a whole, I get nothing. If I break it done to three regex than I can extract the words but then I get the problem with overlaps. I have a dictionary but it's a really big file and using the dictionary to match the words takes a really long time (eg 2+ hours). Also what I'm trying to do is remove words from the dictionary that my regex can detect it.

Comment: @user3013832: overlapping problems can be solved by putting your whole pattern inside a lookahead `(?=...)` (with the pattern enclosed in a capturing group)

Comment: @user3013832: you must edit your question, since it is too broad. You don't want only words (=letters separated by spaces) but expressions, and anybody that answered seems to have understand this.

Answer (score 10):

Use this regex

```
\b[A-Z].*?\b
```

http://rubular.com/r/HG7YJLgkc3

**REGEXPLANATION:**

- `\b` is a word boundary.  It matches the beginning and ending of a word
- `.` matches any character,
- `*` matches the previous character 0 or more times,
- `?` makes the previous `*` non-greedy, so it matches as few characters as it can instead of the the whole string

Comment: I need the "and", "or", and "the" also. This regex also don't allow me to get the possessive ending or the hyphen.

Comment: if you need the whole line, try replacing the last `\b` with `$` for  `\b[A-Z].*?$`.  that should solve both of those problems

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work:

```
"\\b(([A-Z]\\S*)|and|or|the)\\b"
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I need the "and", "or", and "the" also.

Answer (score 1):

Will this achieve what you are looking for?
`[A-Z]\S*\s`

The regex that you use may change slightly with the implementation and you may have to use some flags to allow multiline searches and multiple matches.

Answer (score 0):

This gets yo pretty close:

```
(\b[A-Z].*?\b('s|-|\.|,)?(\s((the|and|of|de)\s)*)?)+
```

Check this: http://rubular.com/r/5LpVm0oKtu

Comment: I need the "and", "or", and "the" also. This regex also don't allow me to get the possessive ending or the hyphen.