# Regex to find Capital Words in a Series while allowing and,to etc. to be between them

Tags: python, regex

So say I have a string such as:

```
Hello There what have You Been Doing. 
I am Feeling Pretty Good and I Want to Keep Smiling.
```

I'm looking for the result:

```
['Hello There', 'You Been Doing', 'I am Feeling Pretty Good and I Want to Keep Smiling']
```

After a long time of head scratching which later evolved into head slamming, I turned to the internet for my answers. So far, I've managed to find the following:

```
r"([A-Z][a-z]+(?=\s[A-Z])(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+)+)"
```

The above works but it clearly does not allow for 'and', 'to', 'for', 'am' (these are the only three I'm looking for) to be in the middle of the words and I can not figure out how to add that in there. I'm assuming I have to use the Pipe to do that, but where exactly do I put that group in?

I've also tried the answers over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225536/regular-expression-to-get-words-that-begin-with-a-capital-letter), but they didn't end up working for me either.

Comment: `anything like 'and' or 'to'` isn't a formal enough definition. Would 'off' be one of those words? What about 'try' ? Are you able to enumerate these words or to provide a better definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to enumerate the words you're ok with being uncapitalized in the middle of a capitalized sentence, I would use an alternation to represent them :

```
\b(?:and|or|but|to|am)\b
```

And use that alternation to match a sequence of capitalized words and accepted uncapitalized words, which must start with a capitalized word :

```
[A-Z][a-z]*(?:\s(?:[A-Z][a-z]*|(?:and|or|but|to|am)\b))*
```

If you are ok with any word of three letters or less (including words like 'owl' or 'try', but not words like 'what') being uncapitalized, you can use the following :

```
[A-Z][a-z]*(?:\s(?:[A-Z][a-z]*|[a-z]{1,3}\b))*
```

Comment: The second one happened to be what I'm looking for, and this works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I guess below works too with itertools.groupby

```
from itertools import groupby
s = 'Hello There what have You Been Doing. I am Feeling Pretty Good and I Want to Keep Smiling.'
[ ' '.join( list(g) ) for k, g in groupby(s.split(), lambda x: x[0].islower() and x not in ['and','to'] ) if not k ]
```

Output:

```
['Hello There',
 'You Been Doing. I',
 'Feeling Pretty Good and I Want to Keep Smiling.']
```